# Using List in FindAll function -C# LinQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am having the below line of code to filter a list

```
items = ctx.listName.ToList().FindAll(x=>x.LocationId= locationId); //int locationId passed as parameter
```

Now, instead of having just one location (locationId), is there a way to have multiple locations and use them in the query?

Like instead of `int locationId` can we use `List<int> locations` and have something like this

```
  items = ctx.listName.ToList().FindAll(x=>x.LocationId in locations)
```

Comment: Your question isn't really related to entity-framework, given that the query is performed in-memory as you've already called `ToList`. But you can use `locations.Contains`. It's likely to be less efficient than trying to do the query in the database though - for that, you'd want something like `ctx.listName.Where(x => locations.Contains(x.LocationId)).ToList()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ Contains() extension method like this.

The Linq Contains Method in C# is used to check whether a sequence or collection (i.e. data source) contains a specified element or not. If the data source contains the specified element, then it returns true else return false

```
List<int> locations= // code to get location id's here

items = ctx.listName.Where(x=>locations.Contains(x.locationId)).ToList();
```